# Get Index of first 'element' in DataRow array

Tags: c#, arrays, datarow

I have an array of data rows initialized as so:

```
DataRow[] rows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToArray();
```

The data table that it is derived from is from an SQL query that returns (among other things) a name, date, address, order code (ex. 00000004) and order type (MAIL or ORDER). The data table is sorted in such a way that its sorted by order code, name, date then order type

In a for loop when I am looping through the rows is there a way to get the row index of the first appearance of a certain address? Because there can be multiple MAIL's and ORDER's from an address and they can be in any order (and the names can be different)

ex:

```
MAIL    Name        00000073     2011-01-10 00:00:00.000    5005 Great Pond
ORDER   Name        00000073     2012-08-02 00:00:00.000    5005 Great Pond
MAIL    Name        00000073     2013-04-15 00:00:00.000    5005 Great Pond
ORDER   Name2       00000073     2012-08-10 00:00:00.000    5005 Great Pond
MAIL    Name2       00000073     2012-09-10 00:00:00.000    5005 Great Pond
```

So I want the index where the first instance of `5005 Great Pond` is to do the various other calculations I am doing.

Comment: If you use linq, you don't necessarily have to use `ToArray` afterwards, `Cast<DataRow>()` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement like this :

```
var row = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().
                        Select(x => x).
                        Where(x => x.Field<string>("Column name").Equals("value")).
                        ElementAt(0);
int index = row == null ? -1 : dt.Rows.IndexOf(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have data rows loaded into an array, you should be able to use **IndexOf** to get the element. Please try the following approach. Please note that the code below is just a guide, I have written it in a notepad as sketch/pseudo code

```
DataRow[] rows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToArray();

foreach (row in rows){
  var address = row["Address"]; // get the address
  var firstAddress = rows.FirstOrDefault(r => (string)r["Address"] == address); // get the first address using LINQ to DataSet
  var indexOfTheFirstAddress = rows.IndexOf(firstAddress);

}
```